# How to create a table with values given by on json object in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a table from an object, with the keys as the columns names, and the values as the rows.
Thank you for your time
App.js code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
   
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // TODO call api.
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Accept", "text/plain");
    myHeaders.append("Authorization","Bearer xxx");

    var requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: myHeaders,
      redirect: "follow",
    };

    fetch("example.com", requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => setData(result))
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">
    { JSON.stringify(data) }
    </div>;
}
         
export default App;
```

The json I want to convert into a table has the following schema:

```
[
    {
        "articleId": xxx,
        "articleName": "xxx",
        "articleNumber": "xxx",
        "articleQuantity": 34,
        "reservedQuantity": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Your JSON is an array so you can just use the `map` function and create `<tr>` for each item with `<td>`s containing values of the item. Use the keys of the first object in the array to create `<th>`.

Comment: @tromgy can you please show some code how to do it bcs i am new to react js, my 2 day

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-table`

Example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useTable } from "react-table";

const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem;

  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;

    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;

      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
`;

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  });

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // TODO call api.
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Accept", "text/plain");
    myHeaders.append("Authorization","Bearer xxx");

    var requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: myHeaders,
      redirect: "follow",
    };

    fetch("example.com", requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => setData(result))
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
  }, []);
  
  // generate dynamically columns from first object from array
  const columns = Object.keys(data[0] || []).map((key) => ({
    Header: key,
    accessor: key
  }));

  return (
    <Styles>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </Styles>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Live example:

[image: Edit zen-perlman-k74rt5]

Comment: Hello, i was reading your code, but here i dont understand how can i put the values being retreived by the api, because you have seted them as fixed. Thank you

Comment: @sudsycloud I'm updated the example